# Are the .Net Action<T> and Func<T> delegate generics available in C++/CX for Windows Store Apps

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I want to use Action and Func delegate generics from .Net for a C++/CX Windows Store App. Are they part of WinRT, too?

```
delegate void f( int );

ref class Sample
{
   ...
   event f^ Rendered; // this works
   event Action<int>^ Rendered; // ??? I want something like this using existing lib without creating templates on my own (which Namespace/Header) ???
   ...
}
```

Comment: If I write using namespace System; the IDE says the namespace System is unknown... any header/assembly reference aditionally required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "C++/CLI for Window Store apps".  Only C# and VB.NET got the Store treatment and can take advantage of the WinRT language projection built into the CLR.  It wouldn't be entirely impossible to use that language projection in C++/CLI as well but you get no help whatsoever from the tooling.

You use a language called C++/CX.  Which is not at all a .NET based language.  It is very much native C++, compiled directly to machine code.  It helps you use WinRT types with language syntax extensions that resemble C++/CLI a lot.  Like the `ref class` syntax.  But since it is not a .NET language it cannot take advantage of .NET classes.

A basic introduction to the language [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700360.aspx).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some Point. Action<T> was used here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/018hxwa8.aspx#Y270 within a C++ sample.

Comment: You do, not your fault.  It is a C++/CLI sample, not a C++ sample.  In spite of the tab title.  Re-iterating, you are using C++/CX.  You can use function pointers and C++11 lambda expressions to get something similar to delegates.  Not quite the same bang for the buck but that's the card that C++ dealt you.